# SwiftKuery, KituraStencil compilation problem with resultSet.forEach()

Tags: swift

I'm a complete beginner at swift development and I can't get the following code to compile:

```
import Kitura
import KituraStencil
import SwiftKuery
import SwiftKuerySQLite
[...]
resultSet.forEach() { row, error in
    guard let row = row else {
        guard let _ = error else {
            // Processed all results
            try response.render("themes.stencil", with: themes, forKey: "themes")
        }
        // Handle error
        return
    }

    /* build 'themes' object */
    [...]
}
[...]
```

Get this error:
 **error: contextual closure type '([Any?]?, Error?, () -> Void) -> Void' expects 3 arguments, but 2 were used in closure body
            resultSet.forEach() { row, error in**

So I tried the following:

```
import Kitura
import KituraStencil
import SwiftKuery
import SwiftKuerySQLite
[...]
resultSet.forEach() { row, error, dummy in
    guard let row = row else {
        guard let _ = error else {
            // Processed all results
            try response.render("themes.stencil", with: themes, forKey: "themes")
        }
        // Handle error
        return
    }

    /* build 'themes' object */
    [...]
}
[...]
```

And then I get this error:
**error: contextual closure type '([Any?]?, Error?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 3 were used in closure body
            resultSet.forEach() { row, error, dummy in**

In both case if I replace **try response.render("themes.stencil", with: themes, forKey: "themes")** with **return** there is no compilation error

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the problem this way (unhandled exception):

```
[...]
resultSet.forEach() { row, error, dummy in
    guard let row = row else {
        guard let _ = error else {
            // Processed all results
            do {
                try response.render("themes.stencil", with: themes, forKey: "themes")
            }
            catch { }
        }
        // Handle error
        return
    }

    /* build 'themes' object */
    [...]
}
[...]
```